# Examples for curve not 1-connected but $h^0(C, O_C)=1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a surface, are there examples for curves on X which not 1-connected, but $h^0(C,O_C)=1$? (Here a curve is an effective divisor, not necessarily reduced or irreducible) (1-connectedness means when it splits into two effective divisors, the two parts have intesection number greater than or equal to 1)

Another question is I am not sure if the dimension of cohomology and 1-connectedness is preserved by linear equivalence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with $X$ smooth : consider a regular surface $X$ with an elliptic fibration having a double fiber $2E$ (typically, an Enriques surface). Then $2E=E+E$ is not 1-connected ($E^2=0$), but one checks easily that $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-2E))=0$, hence $h^0(\mathcal{O}_{2E})=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how do you get the example?  Also I find it hard to check the $H^1(X,O_X(-2E))=0$, is there an easy way to show that?

Comment: 1) Every Enriques surface has such a pencil, look at any book on surfaces (e.g. Barth etc.).                   2) The linear system $|2E|$ is a pencil of elliptic curves; take a smooth $F\in |2E|$. Since $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$, the exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(-F)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_F\rightarrow 0$ gives $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-F))=0$.

Comment: Is that because $H^0(O_X)=H^0(O_F)=k$? Also is pencil here just mean the existence of an elliptic fibration?

Comment: Yes and yes ...

Comment: Since we have $F$ is linear equivalent to $2E$, $O_F$ and $O_{2E}$ define the same invertible sheaf, can we argue $H^0(O_{2E})=k$ directly by this?

Comment: Since we used $H^1(O_{-F})=H^1(O_{-2E})$ in the prove above, I was thinking there is no difference if we apply it to the 0th cohomology group. Maybe I had faute with understanding something?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_F$ and $\mathcal{O}_{2E}$ are certainly not isomorphic, they have different support (namely $F$ and $E$).

Comment: Then $O_{-F}$ and $O_{-2E}$ are not isomorphic? Since they are the dual line bundle of $O_{F}$ and $O_{2E}$..$O_F\otimes_{O_X} O_{-F}=O_X$...?

Comment: I don't understand the notation $O_{-F}$. Aren't you confusing $\mathcal{O}_X(F)$, which is an invertible line bundle on $X$, with $\mathcal{O}_F$, the structure sheaf of $F$, supported on $F\subset X$?

Comment: Ah..you are right, I am sorry..Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

Take $X$ to be a quadratic cone and $C = L_1 + L_2$, the union of two lines on it. Then $L_1\cdot L_2 = 1/2$, so by your definition it is not 1-connected.